# Magnetic monopole's behavior in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-monopoles

I have seen the statement in a physics forum:

> "Imagine a magnetic monopole and a very thin magnet so that the monopole is able to just shoot through the magnet. It then goes around in circles, shooting through the magnet over and over again. If the B field would determine the force on the monopole, it would pick up more and more energy with each revolution. The H field however points from N to S inside a permanent magnet so there is no energy gain for the monopole particle."

I saw this assertion also in a review article on monopoles by Goldhaber. I cannot understand:

1. Why would the monopole circle around the B field? Is it a kind of Lorentz force?
2. Why would it gain energy?
3. Why would the H field not produce the same effect?